# Создание пользователей Linux без группы

Tags: linux, unix, администрирование

Подскажите можно ли создать пользователя в ОС Linux командой adduser, так чтобы при этом не создавалась группа с таким же логином?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/usr/sbin/adduser` — это скрипт-обёртка вокруг целого ряда программ, в частности — `/usr/sbin/useradd`. насколько мне известно, существует она только в дистрибутиве *debian gnu/linux* (и «наследниках»).

вызывая и эту обёртку, и непосредственно программу `useradd`, можно явно указать существующую первичную группу (как и вторичные), в которую должен входить создаваемый пользователь. варианты:

```
$ sudo adduser --ingroup имя-сущуствующей-группы ...
$ sudo adduser --gid номер-существующей-группы ...
$ sudo useradd -g имя-или-номер-существующей-группы ...
$ sudo useradd -N ...
```

последний вариант — `-N` (длинное имя `--no-user-group`) указывает, что в качестве первичной группы следует использовать умолчальную (типа `users`). в некоторых дистрибутивах такое поведение является умолчальным для программы `useradd`. уточняйте это в документации к вашему дистрибутиву или непосредственно в справке: `$ man useradd`

Answer (score 0):

```
useradd --no-user-group username
```